# how to send one message to one number loop with delay android studio

Tags: android, loops, sms, delay

I'd like to ask about this code I wrote. 
 
Tt should send a message to the same number every 5seconds.
My issue is when I run it, it countdowns, then sends the messages.
It doesn't do the 5 seconds countdown.

```
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                        String nums=loopnum.getText().toString();
                        int i = Integer.parseInt(nums);
                        int n = 1;
                    while ( n <= i) {
                                new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

                                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                    public void onFinish() {
                                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        String number = phonenumber.getText().toString();
                                        String sms = smstext.getText().toString();

                                        try {
                                            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, sms, null, null);
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                        }
                                        catch (Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }.start();
                                n++;
                        }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because the while loop is running on the main thread and the countdown is running on a separate thread. So in essence you have started all the timers simultaneously.

Use this instead:

```
String nums = loopnum.getText().toString();
int i = Integer.parseInt(nums);
int n = i * 5000;

new CountDownTimer(n, 5000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           String number = phonenumber.getText().toString();
           String sms = smstext.getText().toString();

           try {
                  SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                  smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, sms, null, null);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               catch (Exception e) {
                                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                          "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                }
    }

    public void onFinish() {

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}.start();
```